# Getting Database values into variable form c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am developing a cricket simulation and i need to retrieve certain statistics from a players data. I've got the following code.

```
public List<float> BattingData()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        string query = "SELECT [INNS], [NOT OUTS], [AVG] FROM [" + batTeam + "] WHERE [Player] = '" + name + "';";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.NextResult())
                {
                    Innings = Convert.ToInt32(reader["INNS"]);
                    NotOuts = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NOT OUTS"]);
                    Avg = Convert.ToSingle(reader["AVG"]);
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();

        OutRatePG = (Innings = NotOuts) / Innings;
        OutRatePB = OutRatePG / 240;
        RunsPB = Avg / 240;

        battingData.Add(OutRatePB);
        battingData.Add(RunsPB);

        return battingData;
    }
```

The error that I am getting is that when I try to divie by 'Innings' it is saying cannot divide by zero, so I think the variables are being returned as zero and no data is being assigned to them.

Comment: Look at your database and see if Innings is 0

Comment: What exactly do you think the line `OutRatePG = (Innings = NotOuts) / Innings;` does? Are you sure you wanted to type the second `=` sign?

Comment: Camilo - thats my fault should be '-'

Comment: You need to sum the innings : Innings += Convert.ToInt32(reader["INNS"]);

Comment: Also, read-up on SQL-Injection, your query is wide-open to exposure to it.  You should ALWAYS parameterize your queries, and especially validate/cleanse the input data from any posts.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the issue:

`while (reader.NextResult())`

What this does is move the reader to the next resultset, ignoring the rest of the rows unread. To advance a reader to the next row, you need to call `reader.Read()` instead.

You have some other issues with your code:

1. You appear to have a separate table for each team. This is incorrect database design. You should create a `Team` table, with each team in it, and then foreign key your `TeamResults` table to it. Query it using `INNER JOIN`.
2. You are concatenating user-entered values to your query. This leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Use parameters instead. (You cannot parameterize a table name, another reason you should do as above 1.)
3. You do not need to check for `HasRows`. If there are no rows, `Read()` will return false.
4. It looks like you only want one row. If that is the case you don't want a `while(reader.Read())` loop, instead `if(reader.Read())`. (If you only need a single value, you can refactor the code to use `command.ExecuteScalar()`.)

Comment: He can't use `ExecuteScalar` because he is returning more than one value in the same recordset. I suspect that the OP doesn't need a while loop at all: probably `if (reader.Read())` would suffice - assuming that there is only one data row per player.

Answer (score 0):

In database records check if value for Innings has **0**
also you can try the below code before performing any operation.

> `> if(Innings>0) { OutRatePG = (Innings - NotOuts) / Innings; }`